# Trouble aligning label in an equation

Tags: equations

I want to align equation label at the right-hand side of the equation. But On using the below code equation label is getting shifted into a new line as you can see from the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\[ u_i =
  \begin{cases}
    v_i,  & \quad r \leq CR\\
    x_i,  & \quad r > CR\\
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to align equation label at the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: You get plenty of errors, which you should not ignore. Remove `\[` and `\]`. Also, `aligned` is redundant, while harmless.

Comment: Your code is not compilable due to the use of `\[` and `\]` inside of a math-environment. If you drop these I get the desired output using your MWE.

Comment: @egreg the usage of `aligned` does change the spacing here (minimal, but it does). But I agree it is redundant.

Comment: Thanks @egreg it worked, Can you please write an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I run `pdflatex` on your example, I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \[
       u_i =
```

followed by several other errors. This means something is wrong in `\[` and that TeX tries its best to get out from the situation, but the final result will most probably be different from the expected.

Note that `\[...\]` is just a shorthand for

```
\begin{equation*}
...
\end{equation*}
```

(because you're using `amsmath`) and at that point you have already opened an `equation` environment, where `equation*` doesn't make sense, does it?

Also `aligned` does nothing at all: it's needed if you have a subordinate alignment to be typeset in `equation` or `equation*` (or other alignment environments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
u_i =
  \begin{cases}
    v_i,  & r \leq CR \\
    x_i,  & r > CR
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Don't add `\quad`.

[image]